# How can i force iOS devices to follow my CSS

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, cross-browser

I am trying to get iPhones to follow the normal CSS i set. Chrome displays it fine and displays it how it should on "mobile view" but when i view it on my iPhone it displays rather differently

Please see screenshots below.

Top Image: Chrome in "Mobile view".

Bottom Image: Iphone6s

Compare the dropdown arrow on the right on the bottom image compared to the top one
[image: Example 1]

[image]

What will be the best way to resolve this?

```
<div class="row SortPanel">
                <div class="col-sm-12 innerSortPanel">
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSort" runat="server" CssClass="innerSortPanel">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrderBy" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOrderBy_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control input-sm">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Date: sooner - later" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="20" Text="Date: later - sooner" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Price: low - high" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="25" Text="Price: high - low" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="10" Text="Duration: shorter - longer" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="30" Text="Duration: longer - shorter" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="15" Text="Title: A - Z" />
                            <asp:ListItem Value="35" Text="Title: Z - A" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 52px;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .sortPanel {
        padding-right:20px;
    }
    .innerSortPanel {
        float:right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the CSS you're using to style the dropdown

Comment: I have now included the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try including [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

As quoted from the website:

> Normalize.css is a customisable CSS file that makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. We researched the differences between default browser styles in order to precisely target only the styles that need normalizing.

Then you can use your own CSS without any problem.